# While loop until you randomly roll selected number, where to put random

Tags: java, loops, random, while-loop

while practicing while loops I tried to make code where you put random number and then your guess how many tries it takes to roll it but I cant declare variable "chance" inside the while but if I put it before it it just keep rolling 1 number.

```
    Random rng = new Random();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Select a number you want to roll");
    int choice = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("You feelin' lucky?\nHow many tries until you get " + choice);
    int tries = input.nextInt();
    int count = 0;
    int chance = rng.nextInt((100)+1);
        while (choice != chance) {
            System.out.println(chance);
            count++;

    }
    System.out.println("You won! It only took " + count + " tries.");
}
```

How can i declare the int chance so it gets into while loop?

Comment: You need to re-assign chance inside the loop... i.e. `chance = rng.nextInt(101);`

Comment: Are you aware it might run forever?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just re-assign chance  to a new value in the while loop :

```
int count = 0;
int chance = rng.nextInt((100)+1);
while (choice != chance) {
    System.out.println(chance);
    chance = rng.nextInt((100)+1);
    count++;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your question, I think you should use the `do-while` loop. It  will enter the loop *atleast* once.

```
Random rng = new Random();
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Select a number you want to roll");
int choice = input.nextInt();
System.out.println("You feelin' lucky?\nHow many tries until you get " + choice);
int tries = input.nextInt();
int count = 0;

do {
   int chance = rng.nextInt((100)+1);
   System.out.println(chance);
   count++;
} while (choice != chance)

System.out.println("You won! It only took " + count + " tries.");
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't *declare* the variable `chance` again. Just re-assign it to a new value.

```
chance = rng.nextInt((100)+1);
```

Issues in the code:

1. Loop never uses `tries`.
2. Code doesn't determine when number of tries is not enough to guess
   the number entered by user

The following addresses them:

```
Random rng = new Random();
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Select a number you want to roll");
int choice = input.nextInt();
System.out.println("You feelin' lucky?\nHow many tries until you get " + choice);
int tries = input.nextInt();
int count = 1;
int chance = rng.nextInt((100) + 1);

while (tries > 0) {
    System.out.println(chance);
    if (choice == chance)
        break;
    chance = rng.nextInt((100) + 1);
    count++;
    tries--;
}

if (choice == chance) {
    System.out.println("You won! It only took " + count + " tries.");
} else {
    System.out.println("You lost");
}
```

Logic:

1. Use `tries` to determine how many times the loop is required to run.
   Decrement it after each run.
2. If choice and chance are equal then control *jumps* out of the loop.
3. The last if condition is to determine whether the user was able to
   guess within the number of *tries*